# Is there a way to print a DateTime in milliseconds?

Tags: java, jodatime

I want the same result as this:

```
 dateTime.toDate().getTime() + ""
```

**NOTE:** That `+ ""` converts it to a `String`.

Does JodaTime's date formatter have a way to do this?  I want to do something like this:

```
dateTime.toString(x);
```

to get the same result.  I tried this:

```
new DateTime().toString("SSS")
```

But this prints the milliseconds in the second, which is not the same as the first example.

Comment: 1) What's the type of "dateTime" on your example? 2) Seconds since when? Seconds in the day?

Comment: @MarceloCalbucci it's a `DateTime`.  Seconds from January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT

Comment: Does `getMillis() / 1000` do what you want?

Comment: @doelleri not exactly, I want it as a `String`.

Comment: [`getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime--) in your example and [`getMillis()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/BaseDateTime.html#getMillis--) both return a `long`...

Comment: @doelleri yeah but I `+ ""` the result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first please note that `dateTime.toDate().getTime()` returns time in millis not in seconds. Also there is no default date format to print date in millis. You can of course implement your own `DateTimeFormatter` but it makes no sense compared to

`String.valueOf(new DateTime().getMillis())`

or

`String.valueOf(new DateTime().getMillis()/1000)`

if you want result in seconds

Comment: Gotcha, if this is the only option I'll accept it as an answer.  Thanks

Comment: *facepalm* you're right about it returning millis.  That must have confused everyone.